# Three-Tier architecture: what should be in data layer?

Tags: web-applications, software-design, three-tier, multi-tier, data-layer

I built a monitoring web application that reads from server log files. After that, business logic pull other information by using a geolocalization service.
Do I should consider both log file and geolocalization database as my data layer?

Comment: Yes, both are data layer

Comment: @slebetman thank you for you answer. My issue is to consider geolocation db as data layer cause I don't handle it directly..Do you think this is not a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes both of these belong in the Data Layer.

See the Wikipedia page on [Data access layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer).

> A data access layer (DAL) in computer software, is a layer of a computer program which provides simplified access to data stored in persistent storage of some kind.

Although the persistent storage is usually a relational database it doesn't have to be.